# Concave Hull implementation

Tags: c#, computational-geometry

I am trying to implement the algorithm described in the following http://repositorium.sdum.uminho.pt/bitstream/1822/6429/1/ConcaveHull_ACM_MYS.pdf

I am using the following class libraries. Loyc libs come from http://core.loyc.net/

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Device.Location;
using Loyc.Collections;
using Loyc.Geometry;
using Loyc;
```

Here is the basic class

```
public class Hulls
{
    private static List<Point<double>> KNearestNeighbors(List<Point<double>> points, Point<double> currentPoint, int k, out int kk)
    {
        kk = Math.Min(k, points.Count - 1);
        var ret = points
            .OrderBy(x => PointMath.Length(new Vector<double>(currentPoint.X - x.X, currentPoint.Y - x.Y)))
            .Take(k)
            .ToList();
        return ret;
    }
    private static double Angle(Point<double> a, Point<double> b)
    {
        var ret = -Math.Atan2(b.Y - a.Y, b.X - a.X);
        return NormaliseAngle(ret);
    }
    private static double NormaliseAngle(double a)
    {
        //while (a < b - Math.PI) a += Math.PI * 2;
        //while (b < a - Math.PI) b += Math.PI * 2;
        if (a < 0.0) { return a + Math.PI + Math.PI; }
        return a;
    }
    private static List<Point<double>> SortByAngle(List<Point<double>> kNearest, Point<double> currentPoint, double angle)
    {
        //kNearest
        //    .Sort((v1, v2) => AngleDifference(angle, Angle(currentPoint, v1)).CompareTo(AngleDifference(angle, Angle(currentPoint, v2))));
        //return kNearest.ToList();
        kNearest = kNearest.OrderByDescending(x => NormaliseAngle(Angle(currentPoint, x) - angle)).ToList();
        return kNearest;
    }

    private static bool CCW(Point<double> p1, Point<double> p2, Point<double> p3)
    {
        var cw = ((p3.Y - p1.Y) * (p2.X - p1.X)) - ((p2.Y - p1.Y) * (p3.X - p1.X));
        return cw > 0 ? true : cw < 0 ? false : true; // colinear 
    }

    private static bool _Intersect(LineSegment<double> seg1, LineSegment<double> seg2)
    {
        return CCW(seg1.A, seg2.A, seg2.B) != CCW(seg1.B, seg2.A, seg2.B) && CCW(seg1.A, seg1.B, seg2.A) != CCW(seg1.A, seg1.B, seg2.B);
    }

    private static bool Intersect(LineSegment<double> seg1, LineSegment<double> seg2)
    {
        if ((seg1.A.X == seg2.A.X && seg1.A.Y == seg2.A.Y) 
            || (seg1.B.X == seg2.B.X && seg1.B.Y == seg2.B.Y))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (_Intersect(seg1, seg2))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public IListSource<Point<double>> KNearestConcaveHull(List<Point<double>> points, int k)
    {
        points.Sort((a, b) => a.Y == b.Y ? (a.X > b.X ? 1 : -1) : (a.Y >= b.Y ? 1 : -1));
        Console.WriteLine("Starting with size {0}", k.ToString());

        DList<Point<double>> hull = new DList<Point<double>>();
        var len = points.Count;

        if (len < 3) { return null; }
        if (len == 3) { return hull; }

        var kk = Math.Min(Math.Max(k, 3), len);

        var dataset = new List<Point<double>>();
        dataset.AddRange(points.Distinct());

        var firstPoint = dataset[0];
        hull.PushFirst(firstPoint);

        var currentPoint = firstPoint;
        dataset.RemoveAt(0);

        double previousAngle = 0;
        int step = 2;
        int i;
        while ((currentPoint != firstPoint || step == 2) && dataset.Count > 0)
        {
            if (step == 5) { dataset.Add(firstPoint); }
            var kNearest = KNearestNeighbors(dataset, currentPoint, k, out kk);
            var cPoints = SortByAngle(kNearest, currentPoint, previousAngle);
            var its = true;
            i = 0;
            while (its == true && i < cPoints.Count)
            {
                i++;
                int lastPoint = 0;
                if (cPoints[i - 1] == firstPoint)
                {
                    lastPoint = 1;
                }
                int j = 2;
                its = false;
                while (its == false && j < hull.Count - lastPoint)
                {
                    LineSegment<double> line1 = new LineSegment<double>(hull[step - 2], cPoints[i - 1]);
                    LineSegment<double> line2 = new LineSegment<double>(hull[step - 2 - j], hull[step - 1 - j]);

                    //its = LineMath.ComputeIntersection(line1, line2, out pfrac, LineType.Segment);
                    its = Intersect(line1, line2);
                    j++;
                }
            }
            if (its == true)
            {
                return KNearestConcaveHull(points, kk + 1);
            }
            currentPoint = cPoints[i - 1];
            hull.PushLast(currentPoint);
            previousAngle = Angle(hull[step - 1], hull[step - 2]);
            dataset.Remove(currentPoint); 
            step++;
        }
        bool allInside = true;
        i = dataset.Count;
        while (allInside == true && i > 0)
        {
            allInside = PolygonMath.IsPointInPolygon(hull, dataset[i - 1]);
            i--;
        }
        if (allInside == false) { return KNearestConcaveHull(points, kk + 1); }
        return hull;
    }
}
```

The above is supposed to pick a new edge for the boundary based on the furthest right-hand turn from the previous edge going around the point set counterclockwise. The code seems to pick the correct first edge from the initial vertex which has the lowest y-value, but then does not pick the next edge correctly when the offset angle is nonzero. I think the issue is the SortByAngle or Angle. -atan2 would return the clockwise turn, correct? Possibly I should be adding the offset angle?

EDIT (SOLUTION): Found the issue after following Eric's helpful advice provided in the first comment to the question. It was SortByAngle and Angle:

```
private static double Angle(Point<double> a, Point<double> b)
    {
        var ret = Math.Atan2(b.Y - a.Y, b.X - a.X);
        return NormaliseAngle(ret);
    }

    private static double NormaliseAngle(double a)
    {
        if (a < 0.0) { return a + Math.PI + Math.PI; }
        return a;
    }

    private static List<Point<double>> SortByAngle(List<Point<double>> kNearest, Point<double> currentPoint, double angle)
    {
        //kNearest = kNearest.OrderByDescending(x => NormaliseAngle(Angle(currentPoint, x) - angle)).ToList();
        kNearest.Sort((a, b) => NormaliseAngle(Angle(currentPoint, a) - angle) > NormaliseAngle(Angle(currentPoint, b) - angle) ? 1 : -1);
        return kNearest;
    }
```

Comment: Debugging your program and keeping us up-to-date about the state of your debugging session is not an effective use of StackOverflow. This isn't a service for finding your bugs.  If you want to know if a method is correct then **write test cases for that method**.  If you want more good advice on how to debug a small buggy program that you just wrote, see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @EricLippert, thanks for the advice. I was simply trying to provide as much info as possible but appreciate what you are saying. I am in the process of writing unit tests at the moment. I will edit my question accordingly after.

Comment: Any way - using Theraot.Core makes you have to use "extern alias" and give an alias to that dll, otherwise you'll find yourself having ambigous calls vs System.Linq functions...They built that dll in the same namespace.

Comment: Hi, Do you have an updated version of this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some bug:

```
var kNearest = KNearestNeighbors(dataset, currentPoint, k, out kk);
```

Change the kk to just some var. You override the incrementation of that "kk" value, and then you're getting StackOverflow exceptions.

Change your code to the following:

```
int someVal;    
var kNearest = KNearestNeighbors(dataset, currentPoint, k, out someVal);
```